# Почему WordPress генерирует ссылку href="#", если у пункта меню есть подменю?

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap

При интеграции меню в WordPress наблюдаю следующую картину:

если пункт меню (категория) не имеет подменю, то WordPress генерирует ссылку на эту категорию:

```
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-47 nav-item"><a title="Первый уровень" href="http://domen/category/id_4/" class="nav-link">Первый уровень</a></li>
```

а если у пункта меню первого уровня есть подменю, то WordPress генерирует в ссылке путь - href="#"

```
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-47 nav-item">
  <a title="Первый уровень" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-51">Первый уровень</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-51" role="menu">
      <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-53 nav-item"><a title="Второй уровень 1" href="http://domen/category/id_5/" class="dropdown-item">Второй уровень 1</a></li>
      <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-54 nav-item"><a title="Вторй уровень 2" href="http://domen/category/id_6/" class="dropdown-item">Второй уровень 2</a></li>
      <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-52 nav-item"><a title="Второй уровень 3" href="http://domen/category/id_7/" class="dropdown-item">Второй уровень 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить WordPress генерировать ссылку на категорию первого уровне, если у нее есть выпадающее меню.

Comment: при клике на обычную ссылку будет совершен переход и подменю никогда не покажется, за этим и сделан `#`

Comment: а как же наведение? подменю показываеся по наведению даже сейчас, в ситуации, которую я рассказал сейчас

Comment: вам тогда придется лезть в шаблон этого подменю и там поправлять это дело

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить WordPress генерировать ссылку на
>   категорию первого уровне, если у нее есть выпадающее меню.

Создать меню в админке с какими нужно пунктами с нужной иерархии.

Но делать верхний уровень ссылкой на страницу - неправильно. Так проблемно будет воспользоваться подуровнями меню. На мобилках и вовсе невозможно.